# MongoDB update deep nested field in the document

Tags: mongodb

I try to update a field in the MongoDb like this
https://mongoplayground.net/p/_jFYJGi8z46

However i get this error
fail to run update: write exception: write errors: [The array filter for identifier 'e2' was not used in the update { $set: { sizes.$[e1].wares$[e2].reserved: "2" } }]

I can't find a bug :( ... it must be a very simple one

Comment: missing a [dot](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EO_9p_Wb_Pd)?

Answer (score 0):

Right... one dot was missing :( This is solved
https://mongoplayground.net/p/obdFTr6G1kj